# select multiple related rows of same group onlongclick for list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i plan to have a list view which when onlongclick, will be able to select all the subrows/related rows.

## Example

*Input*:
Long click on user name/age/birthday
*Output*:
Return the username, age and birthday.

## Problem

Will only return the user name if you long click on it and not the age and birthday.

I didn't include the age and birthday value to be display in the toast cause the app will display an error and stop functioning.

Latest:
Have shown the Adapter and object class on 26th Nov17

Custom layout of list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username:"
            android:background="#FF2400"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_user_name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#FF2400"
            android:text="Username"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Age:"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_user_age"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Age"
            android:gravity="left"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Birthday:"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:id="@+id/text_user_birthday"
                android:text="Birthday"
                android:gravity="left"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

DataListActivity (Listview activity)

```
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                               int index, long arg3)
                {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataListActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Notice");
                builder.setMessage("Launching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?");
                final View clicklist = v;
                final int position = index;

builder.setPositiveButton("Launch missile", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String selname= ((EditText) clicklist.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name)).getText().toString();
                     //   String selage= ((EditText) clicklist.findViewById(R.id.text_user_age)).getText().toString();
                        String selbirthday= ((EditText) clicklist.findViewById(R.id.text_user_birthday)).getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(DataListActivity.this,selname + selage + selbirthday,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

LayoutAdapter

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
List list = new ArrayList();

static class LayoutHandler
{
    TextView NAME,AGE,BIRTHDAY;
}
public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

@Override
public void add (Object object)
{
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if (row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name);
        layoutHandler.AGE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_age);
        layoutHandler.BIRTHDAY = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_birthday);
    }
    else
    {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
    layoutHandler.AGE.setText(dataProvider.getAge());
    layoutHandler.BIRTHDAY.setBIRTHDAY(dataProvider.getBirthday());


    return row;
}

@Override
public void clear()
{
    list.clear();
}
```

}

```
public class DataProvider {

private String Name;
private String Age;
private String Birthday;
```

....getter and setters method

Comment: inside toast you are giving selaccount, what is that?? actually selname is one has to be there na??

Comment: Use the model object at index=position instead of the view, else you may add the long clicks to each View in layout

Comment: Hi can give more example of how to use model object at  index = position

Comment: _app will display an error and stop functioning_. add error report here...

Comment: We need to see your data structure (the objects in the list or array) and your adapter.

Comment: Hi have included the objects and adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing your code, i found following problems :-

In List adapter you didn't set the tag to **row** so it always return null **layoutHandler** and your casting EditText to TextView , i didn't get your point here if you want TextView then use same view in XML.

So the ListAdapter Looks like this.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        EditText NAME,AGE,BIRTHDAY;
    }
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add (Object object)
    {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NAME = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name);
            layoutHandler.AGE = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_age);
            layoutHandler.BIRTHDAY = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_birthday);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.AGE.setText(dataProvider.getAge());
        layoutHandler.BIRTHDAY  .setText(dataProvider.getBirthday());


        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
        list.clear();
    }


}
```

and coming to the actual problem i.e. ListView OnItemLongClickListener crashing. You just have to change

```
final View clicklist = v;
```

to

```
final View clicklist = arg0.getChildAt(index);
```

and then you go. :)

Comment: Thanks for advising and for posting codes here. Will run through the code when i am back home!

Comment: This line vs all the weird object models i been throwing in for months, thanks suraj, you are a lifesaver!!!
final View clicklist = arg0.getChildAt(index);

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: hi i run into some bugs, don't mind advising.
At my 5th item of the listview, my app crash.
And the crash report read as null reference.
Any idea why only the 5th item and beyond return null reference.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to this is to

1) Create a Custom Class for example Data and add properties that you
want to display within that class.

2) Create an Adapter and populate your adapter with arraylist of Data class.

3) Retrieve the values from listview using onItemClicklistener.

Comment: Most probably cause of error is that your age and birthday value is not being set somewhere in your listview .... that is causing the exception.

Comment: You should check the object that is being filled with age and birthday value see if it is being set or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advising,i have no problem populating the list view, had done these.

I have difficulty retrieving the data as a custom class object from list view. Need to seek your advice.

Comment: Hi populate data as in which activity you looking at? Have added the data adapter and object class

Answer (score 0):

modify your toast

```
Toast.makeText(DataListActivity.this,"name"+selname+"age"+
 selage+"DOB"+ selbirthday,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Nope, is not because of the toast, the toast is something i am testing out as a group object!

Comment: i believe is something along the line of Marcos comment above

Comment: Create the modle class and insert the vaues of name age, and DOB , have you used adapter for the list view, you can  get the item index there in getView

Comment: HI sir? Thanks for advising, I have enclosed my adapter get view method above. Is it possible to advise how to do so?

Comment: In adapter you are not setting the Tag. use row.setTag(layoutHandler). And listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                               int index, long arg3)
                { use final View clicklist = arg0.getChildAt(index);